# Did we change something today

Tags: bug

I can nolonger see addtional comments if they are  enough tht some are hidden at first. Nor can I see the points I have earned today or the comments (at the top not the actual posts) people have made on my posts. (I can see that in other sO sites)

I also can no longer add comments.

And I keeo getting teh Capcha which I as an older person find virtually impossible to read. I had to go through many differnt ones before I foudn one I could read.  Can we make this easier to read?

Comment: I've not had this problem, so it must be a bug on your account somehow?

Comment: We have had a few reports about IE 8 / IE 9 issues, coinciding with the Microsoft patch Tuesday. We, at Stack Exchange, didn't make any large changes that would effect these browsers specifically.

Comment: Those sound like things that would happen if the Javascript isn't loading correctly.  Do you use a selective blocker like NoScript?  (Yesterday or today I had to approve a new SE domain -- don't remember what, but it had "test" in its name.)  Does this happen to you in more than one browser?  Can you add info about your browser (with version) and OS?

Comment: I have the same issues using IE9.  I can add comments using a different browser (chrome).  I think Oded's comment should be an answer (and I'll delete my 'answer'.)

Comment: I have tried to reproduce using an IE 8 / Windows 7 virtual machine, but everything works just right. Do you have any extensions installed? Ad blockers?

Comment: Can you confirm whether this is still an issue? I've had a report that this no longer happens.

Comment: Today I can add comments, in the same IE 9.  I did not get any patches since yesterday.  So I think it's been fixed (at least for me).

Comment: @thursdaysgeek - We didn't change anything that should have effected comments. Not in some time. Whatever it was seems to have gone back to normal.